# Why does an optional property have to return something?

Tags: swift

So i've got this read only property:

```
  private var allProducts: [String]? {
        if let selectedProductSeries = selectedProductSeries {
            return ["someProduct"]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Great, that does what I want, but my question is why do I have to be exhaustive in my `if/else`. I'm marking it as optional and thus what I'd expect to happen is that if I don't return anything its just nil. But of course if I get rid of the `else` it complains saying: `Missing return in function expected to return: [String]?` Which is funny because the message says its *expecting* me to return something even though its optional.

Why is this?

Comment: The language is young, implicit return could be added in the future. I personally would not like it in Swift because the Swift style is more about explicity.

Comment: just return a conditional unwrap that if it fails it will return nil

Comment: Also looks like you still using Swift 1.x otherwise it would not complain having a return in both if else conditions. BTW return ["someProduct"] ??

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain "conditional unwrap..."? And, what's bad about `["someProduct"]`?

Comment: @LeoDabus the `["someProduct"]` is just so I could post this without include anything that could identify the project I'm working on.

Comment: If you add some hypothetical info into your question i could show you how that would look like

Comment: Note that your entire method body could be rewritten as `return selectedProductSeries?["someProduct"]`. Swift’s general philosophy is “implicit types, explicit control flow,” and the language is pretty good about providing conveniences that make that play out well.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that errors might occur more often, if the `return nil` was implicitly added. Inside of a function/method which contains many `if`- or `switch`-statements, you could easily overlook, that you might fall through each and every statement. An explicit `return nil` forces you to deal with that possibility.

Comment: Exactly so — and moreover, making `return nil` implicit would ruin the whole point of checked optionals, namely to force you to think about the nil case in every situation where it might arise. If they start doing things like that, they might as well do away with the whole business of optionals being part of the static type system, and revert to Objective-C’s philosophy of “make noop the implicit default for nil.”

Comment: @PaulCantrell if something returns an optional then its implicit return value is `nil` before we do anything anyway. Im not sure what your point is.

Comment: @PeterFoti could you give an example?

Comment: @PeterFoti Does not compile: `func f() -> Int? { }` Also does not compile: `let g: () -> Int? = { }` Can you explain what you mean by “its implicit return value is nil?” That is true in other languages (Ruby, for example), but AFAIK there is nothing like that in Swift.

Comment: @PaulCantrell If I write `var someVar: String?` and you get the value of `someVar` before it is set, its going to be nil. Thus, its implicit return value is `nil` before we do anything. So in my question, I only want to return a value if one condition is met, otherwise I want it to be treated as if nothing has changed (because it hasn't).

Comment: @PeterFoti Ah, your comment makes more sense. `var someVar: String?` is a variable, not a function, so it doesn’t have a return value. It’s _control flow_ that Swift seems to always make explicit, and a variable — not being a function — has none. In other words, in forcing you to write “return nil,” I’d say it’s it more forcing the “return” and than forcing the “nil” that’s the point.